# About rename downloaded images in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am very new in scrapy so for me it is difficult to do very basic things in scrapy. My problem is that I can't rename my downloaded images. I copied part of my code from this website:"http://scrapingauthority.com/scrapy-download-images/" but it doesn't work. So my spider's code is this:

```
from scrapy import Request, Spider
from Imagenes.items import ImagenesItem

class AuthorSpider(Spider):
    name = 'imagenpruebarenombrar'
    start_urls = [
        "http://quotes.toscrape.com/",        
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        item = ImagenesItem()
        img_urls = [
            "http://automationpractice.com/img/p/5/5-large_default.jpg",
            "http://automationpractice.com/img/p/6/6-large_default.jpg",
            "http://automationpractice.com/img/p/7/7-large_default.jpg",
        ]
        img_name = [ #These are the names that I want to my images
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
        ]
        item["image_urls"] = img_urls
        item["image_name"] = img_name
        return item
```

The code of items:

```
import scrapy

class ImagenesItem(scrapy.Item):
    images = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    image_name = scrapy.Field()
```

Code of Pipelines:

```
class CustomImageNamePipeline(ImagesPipeline): #I copied this code from the website

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        return [Request(x, meta={'image_name': item["image_name"]})
                for x in item.get('image_urls', [])]

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return '%s.jpg' % request.meta['image_name']
```

My settings:

```
BOT_NAME = 'Imagenes'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['Imagenes.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'Imagenes.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = r"C:\Users\Orlando\Imagenes"
```

Comment: do you get error message or images with old name ?

Comment: you have to add `CustomImageNamePipeline` in your settings.

Comment: I get the images with old name

Answer (score 3):

First you need to edit your `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'Imagenes.pipelines.CustomImageNamePipeline': 1}
```

Next in your `pipelines.py`:

```
class CustomImageNamePipeline(ImagesPipeline): #I copied this code from the website


    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image in item.get('image_urls', []):
            yield scrapy.Request(image["url"], meta={'image_name': image["name"]})

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return '%s.jpg' % request.meta['image_name']
```

and finally in your spider:

```
def parse(self, response):

    item = ImagenesItem()

    img_urls = [
        "http://automationpractice.com/img/p/5/5-large_default.jpg",
        "http://automationpractice.com/img/p/6/6-large_default.jpg",
        "http://automationpractice.com/img/p/7/7-large_default.jpg",
    ]
    img_names = [ #These are the names that I want to my images
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
    ]

    images = []
    for image_url, image_name in zip(img_urls, img_names):
        images.append({'url': image_url, 'name': image_name})

    item["image_urls"] = images
    yield item
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now I get an error: NameError: name 'ImagesPipeline' is not defined

Comment: You must import it first. See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#custom-images-pipeline-example

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your `CustomImageNamePipeline` instead of `ImagesPipeline` to settings

If you have class in file `pipelines.py` then add to `settings.py`

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'pipelines.CustomImageNamePipeline': 1}
```

or maybe with project name

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'Imagenes.pipelines.CustomImageNamePipeline': 1}
```

---

If you have all code in one file (without creating project) then add it the same file

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'__main__.CustomImageNamePipeline': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I get an error like this: NameError: name 'ImagesPipeline' is not defined

Comment: in which file you get it ? Did you import `ImagesPipeline` in `pipelines.py` - `from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline`

Comment: Scrapy documentation for [Downloading and processing files and images](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html)

Comment: I only have a question: Why I can't find the method "file_path" in documentation?

Comment: it seems they forgot to mention it. In source code is `file_path` is used insteaf of `file_key` which is deprecated. Maybe they remove `file_key` from documentation and forgot to add `file_path`. [source code for file_path](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.5/scrapy/pipelines/files.py#L442)